# 2 single pole switches for two fixtures

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have 14/3 power coming in (black, red, white, copper).
Switch 1 is for an inside light there is 14/3 running from the switch to light.
Switch 2 is for an outside light there is 14/2 running from switch to light.
Nothing is currently connected and I'm unsure how to wire the switches with the extra wires from the 14/3.

Comment: What's the voltage between the black and red wires in the incoming 14/3 cable?

Comment: This really needs a picture of the wiring inside all the boxes involved. What's currently there (including switches/outlets/fixtures), and labeling of where you want to end up.

Comment: I'll try and add a picture later when I'm back at the house. Currently there is 14/3 coming in to the bottom of a 2 gang box. All the wires on that are capped off. There is another 14/3 going out the top of the box on one side and 14/2 going out the top on the other side. All of these are capped of as well. Currently there nothing is connected and there are no switches. It looks like someone had set it up to put things in and never finished.

Comment: Check to see what breaker/breakers control those wires/

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify.  Make sure to do this from the same browser you originally asked, as your account may depend on the cookie from that browser. (Register your account to an email/facebook to avoid that problem.)